# Downloading Logs & DBs as Non-Root User

Tags: debian, rsync, scp

I am the forever noob to linux webhosting.. and rather than deal with terminal width/height/length issues while hunting errors, I set-up a bunch of bash alias commands on my ubuntu 20.04 local machine to simply execute a `scp` commandm to download whatever log and open it locally in my gedit gui.

**PROBLEM**:
Now that I have learned about the best practice of using a non-root user and disabling root ssh ability, I have a bunch of bash alias commands that will not work because I now ssh to the server as a non-root user that has to use `sudo su` to become root and do anything (a worthy trade off for security peace of mind).

**Question:**
Does anyone know how to change the following commands so that a non-root use can execute them:

```
alias pae="scp root@prodserver:/var/log/apache2/error.log ~/Downloads/logs/prod/error-access-logs/prod-apache-error.log && gedit ~/Downloads/logs/prod/error-access-logs/prod-apache-error.log"


alias dbdl="rsnyc -aHAXSv root@prodserver:/dbbackdir ~/Downloads/dbbackups"
```

For each of the above commands...

I need to replace `root@prodserver` with `adminuser@prodserver`, pass the `sudo su` command and somehow automatically pass the adminuser's password to become root in order for my bash aliases to keep their prior end-user convenience.

I am punching way above my weight-class on this one.

Any tips?

**UPDATE:**

I found a useful tutorial that shows how add non-root access to files. Unfortunately, following the instructions exactly as written didn't work:

grant non-root user apache2 log access
https://gist.github.com/angela-d/8a2416034ea7ed89ecde37147e8711ba

Note: the tutorial doesn't say if it is applicable to Debian 10.5 or not, which could explain why things aren't working.

As instructed I ran `setfacl -m g:adminuser:rx /var/log/apache2/*`

However, when I run `getfacl /var/log/apache2/` the output **does not** show adminuser as having r-x access to `/var/log/apache2/*` only root user continues to have access..

I also tried changing from group to user (using 'u' instead of 'g') for `setfacl -m g:adminuser:rx /var/log/apache2/*`  but still no luck.

hhmmm..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Listen to nagging voice in your head.* I doubled-checked my previous solution and realized I had created a security hole by granting my adminuser permissions to all the directories under /var, so I deleted it and will live with "*noob flavored*" egg on my face. :-)

FYI, I used `setfacl -b g:adminuser:rx /var/*` to undo my foolishness.

In any case, to correct set permission for my non-root user to access apache logs, without creating a security hole, I used:

`setfacl -m u:adminuser:rx /var/log/apache2/*.log`

And finally `getfacl /var/log/apache2/` showed that `adminuser` had rights to the apache2 error.log  (and no other sensitive directories).

From there, I tested my original bash alias with the new adminuser and everything worked perfectly:

```
alias pae="scp adminuser@prodserver:/var/log/apache2/error.log ~/Downloads/logs/prod/error-access-logs/prod-apache-error.log && gedit ~/Downloads/logs/prod/error-access-logs/prod-apache-error.log"
```

With regards the rsync command above, it seems safest to save my db backups directly `adminuser` user's home directory and rsync them to my local machine from there rather than trying to apply `setfacl` in too many places and causing security holes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to be root on the server to read the log files. Maybe something like:

```
alias pae="ssh prodserver sudo cat /var/log/apache2/error.log" > ~/Downloads/logs/prod/error-access-logs/prod-apache-error.log && gedit ~/Downloads/logs/prod/error-access-logs/prod-apache-error.log"
```

If you need more files, I would use `tar` to ball them uo into one that can transferred, but for a way to transfer only changes (like `rsync` does) I would suggest looking at whether there's a group you can put your ordinary user into so he can read those files.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I just tried your solution, but I get this in response  "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"